# How to draw quivers?

Tags: diagrams

I'm trying to draw graphs and especially quivers, for instance the quiver made of one vertice and one loop upon it. A simple way please ?
(PS. not sure about the tag)

Edit : To be clear a quiver is nothing but a directed graph where loops and multiple arrows between vertices are allowed. No link with graphs of functions!

Edit : ok so to be clear here are pictures :

[image: a quiver]

[image: a quiver where every arrow is given a name]

[image: a loop]

So you see there are vertices, arrows between those vertices and both vertices and arrows are given a name by a letter upon them. 
And you can have an arrow that starts and ends at the same vertice (but this case is not so important, it's ok if it's not doable).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please clarify your question, or you might get a drawing of a container for arrows and a drawing of what you really want in addition to the drawing of a quiver plot which has already been posted. :-)

Comment: You're right, done :) But well I don't think that quiver has any other mathematical definition so...

Comment: Still not clear to me... maybe a picture of an actual graph could be helpful. `:)`

Comment: Oh come on :p You know what is a graph in graph theory. Well a quiver is a directed graph, but we can have multiple arrows between two vertices. We can also have an arrow that starts from a vertice and ends at the same vertice.

Comment: quiver is for the rest of the nonmathematician world is a flow diagram showing any field vector as in meteorology, fluid dynamics etc. unfortunately graph theory is the esoteric one not the other way around.

Comment: You mean.... There is a nonmathematician world ??

Comment: Yes, we were afraid that this confrontation day would come

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some examples reproducing those in [some notes about representations of algebras](http://www.math.washington.edu/~jstarx/files/QuiversAndPathAlgebras.pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

Example 3
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow[r,"\alpha"] & 2
\end{tikzcd}
\]

Example 4
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow[r] & 2 \arrow[r] & \cdots \arrow[r] & n
\end{tikzcd}
\]

Example 5
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
& 2 \arrow[d] \\
1 \arrow[r] & 5 & 3 \arrow[l] \\
& 4 \arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

Example 6
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow[out=0,in=90,loop]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

Example 7
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow[out=0,in=30,loop,swap,"\alpha_1"]
  \arrow[out=90,in=120,loop,swap,"\alpha_2"]
  \arrow[out=180,in=210,loop,swap,"\cdots"]
  \arrow[out=270,in=300,loop,swap,"\alpha_n"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

Example 8
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow[r,bend left,"\alpha"] \arrow[r,bend right,swap,"\beta"] & 2
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

And two of your examples

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[arrow style=tikz,>=stealth,row sep=4em]
1 \arrow[rr,"\gamma_{13}"]
  \arrow[dr,shift left=.4ex]
  \arrow[dr,shift right=.4ex,swap,"\gamma_{12}"]
&& 2 \\
& 3 \arrow[ur,shift left=.4ex]
  \arrow[ur,shift left=1.2ex]
  \arrow[ur,shift right=.4ex]
  \arrow[ur,shift right=1.2ex,swap,"\gamma_{23}"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow[drr,shift right=.2ex,swap,"\beta_1"] &
2 \arrow[dr,"\beta_2"] &&
3 \arrow[dl,swap,"\beta_3"] &
4 \arrow[dll,shift left=.2ex,"\beta_4"] \\
&& 5
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Although the code is pretty clear, can you give some basic documentation ?

Comment: @krirkrirk The documentation of `tikz-cd` is quite extensive; do `texdoc tikz-cd` from a terminal or look for it at http://texdoc.net (type `tikz-cd` in the search box).

Answer (score 4):

Something like that, made with `pstricks`?

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\[ \psset{ArrowInside=->, ArrowInsidePos=0.25, arrowinset=0.25 , linewidth=0.6pt, nodesep=-1.5pt, colsep=1.2cm, offset =1ex}
\begin{psmatrix}[mnode = circle]
N & P
%%%
 \ncline{1,1}{1,2}\ncline{1,2}{1,1}\nccircle[angleA=90,nodesep=0pt]{->}{1,1}{.5cm}
\end{psmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[pdf, x11names]{article}
\usepackage{boondox-ds}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

$ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0 ,nodesep=3pt, labelsep=2pt, colsep=1.4cm, radius = 0.15, linewidth=0.3pt, fillstyle=solid, shortput=nab}
\begin{psmatrix}
    \Cnode[fillcolor=green](0,0){N} & & \Cnode[fillcolor=DeepSkyBlue3, \linewidth=0.3pt](0,0){P} \\
    & \Cnode[fillcolor=IndianRed3](0,0){R} \\
    %%
    \psset{ linewidth=0.8pt}
    \ncline{N}{P}^{\gamma_{13}}
    \nput{135}{N}{\mathbbb C^{d_1}}
    \nput{45}{P}{\mathbbb C^{d_3}}
    \nput[labelsep=4pt]{-90}{R}{\mathbbb C^{d_2}}
    \ncline[offset = 1.5pt]{N}{R}\ncline[offset=-1.5pt]{N}{R}\nbput{\gamma_{1,3}}
    \ncline[offset = 1.5pt]{R}{P}\ncline[offset=-1.5pt]{R}{P}
    \ncline[offset = 4.5pt]{R}{P}\ncline[offset=-4.5pt]{R}{P}\nbput{\gamma_{2,3}}
\end{psmatrix}
 $

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a last one, as close as possible to your image:

```
\documentclass[pdf, x11names]{article}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

 \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0,nodesep=-1pt, labelsep=2pt, colsep=1.4cm, radius = 0.2, fillstyle=solid, shortput=nab}
\begin{pspicture}
    \pnode(0,0){P}
    \Cnode[linecolor =white](0,0){N}
    {\psset{doubleline, doublesep=2.5\pslinewidth, linecolor=DodgerBlue4, doublecolor=Gold4!75, angleA=180}
    \nccircle[doubleline, linecolor=DodgerBlue4, angleA=180]{-}{N}{0.7}
    \nccircle[doubleline, linecolor=DodgerBlue4, angleA=180, arrowscale =0.8 0.3]{->}{N}{0.7}}
    \nbput{\boldmath\color{IndianRed3}\itshape\bfseries x}
    \pscircle[fillcolor=DodgerBlue4!70, linecolor=red](P){0.2}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks perfect ! Any explanation on how to do this ? Or a reference?

Comment: In a moment, I'll complete with another example and explanations. You can take a look at the documentation of `pst-node`. Roughly, I put nodes of various sorts in a matrix of nodes, then make node connections (`\nc…`).