# Tikz for Gabriel and Auslander-Reiten quivers

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

In the context of representation theory, direct graphs —known there as *quivers*— appear all the time. Here are  a few samples (from the book of Assem, Simson andSkowroński) First, a couple of gabriel quivers:

[image]

These are in general directed graphs which allow parallel arrows (that is, the graph need not be simple) and loops.

Next, the beautiful (!) A-R quiver of $E_6$ (which is missing a few dashed lines denoting the translation functor, but still)

[image]

I am 100% sure people working in the subject have come up with Tikz styles, tricks and whatnot to draw these things, but googling does not come up with much. In particular (and amazingly!) there is no AR quiver at http://www.texample.net/tikz/

> Do you have any relevant resources for this?

Comment: One can find very impressive examples of AR quivers in the book by Gabriel and Roiter, which googlebooks has [here](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=Gb3ZaoABbZAC&lpg=PA156&dq=gabriel%20roiter&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232968/how-to-draw-quivers ?

Comment: To my no-math-seeing eyes these are bunch of nodes and arrows fit for a good foreach loop. But I don't know what is happening to the content of these nodes or what the rules are for the direction selection or why you have a diagonal connection in the first one.

Comment: The content of the nodes in the 2nd type of quiver could be computed but I am willing to type it in :-) (It would be maximally cute to have TeX find indecomposable modules, of course)

Comment: It's quite easy to do with the `psmatrix` environment from `pst-node`.

Answer (score 7):

The final diagram poses no real problem: there are just a few patterns that I called `\qL` (left), `\qR` (right), `\qM` (middle), `\qC` and `\qCC` (center); also the modules are denoted with an abbreviation for `smallmatrix`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\ind}[2]{%
  \begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\end{smallmatrix}%
}

\newcommand{\qL}[2]{\ind{#1}{#2}\arrow[dr]}
\newcommand{\qR}[2]{\ind{#1}{#2}\arrow[dl]}
\newcommand{\qC}[2]{\ind{#1}{#2}\arrow[d]}
\newcommand{\qM}[2]{\ind{#1}{#2}\arrow[dl]\arrow[dr]}
\newcommand{\qCC}[2]{\qM{#1}{#2}\arrow[d]}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1em,column sep=1em]
\qL{0}{00001} &&&& \qR{0}{10000} \\
%
& \qM{0}{00011} & \qC{1}{00000} & \qM{0}{11000} \\
%
\qL{0}{00010} && \qCC{1}{11111} && \qR{0}{01000} \\
%
& \qM{1}{11110} & \qC{0}{11111} & \qM{1}{01111} \\
%
\qL{1}{11100} && \qCC{1}{12221} && \qR{1}{00111} \\
%
& \qM{1}{12211} & \qC{1}{01110} & \qM{1}{11221} \\
%
\qL{0}{01111} && \qCC{2}{12321} && \qR{0}{11110} \\
%
& \qM{1}{01221} & \qC{1}{11211} & \qM{1}{12210} \\
%
\qL{1}{00110} && \qCC{1}{12321} && \qR{1}{01100} \\
%
& \qM{1}{11210} & \qC{0}{01110} & \qM{1}{01211} \\
%
\qL{0}{11100} && \qCC{1}{01210} && \qR{0}{00111} \\
%
& \qL{0}{01100} & \qC{1}{00100} & \qR{0}{00110} \\
%
&& \ind{0}{00100}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The Gabriel quivers pose no problem either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1em,column sep=1em]
& \circ \arrow[dl,swap,"\beta"] \arrow[dd,swap,"\mu"] \\
\circ && \circ \arrow[ul,swap,"\alpha"] \arrow[dl,"\gamma"] \\
& \circ \arrow[ul,"\delta"]
\end{tikzcd}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1em,column sep=1em]
\circ \\
& \circ \arrow[ul,swap,"\mu"] \\
&& \circ \arrow[ul,swap,"\lambda"] \arrow[dl,swap,"\beta"] \\
\circ & \circ \arrow[l,swap,"\varepsilon"] &&
   \circ \arrow[ul,swap,"\alpha"] \arrow[dl,"\gamma"] \\
&& \circ \arrow[ul,"\delta"]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]