# How to draw this quiver in latex?

Tags: packages, draw

I tried to draw this in latex.

[image]

But not successful. How could I draw this quiver in latex? Thank you very much.

Comment: could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Please see the link and try  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237778/tikz-for-gabriel-and-auslander-reiten-quivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions: one based on `pstricks`, the other on `tikz-cd`. For the pstricks solution, you can compile with `pdflatex` if you launch it with option `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX). Alternatively, you can compile with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

$ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, nodesep=4pt,  colsep=0.8cm,  rowsep=0.9cm,  linewidth=0.5pt, linejoin=1}
\begin{psmatrix}
  %%% nodes
  & β& & α\\
  b &  & a &  & c
  %%%arrows
  \ncline{1,2}{2,1} \ncline{1,2}{2,3}%
  \ncline{2,3}{2,1}\ncline{2,3}{2,5}%
  \ncline{2,3}{1,4}\ncline{2,5}{1,4}
\end{psmatrix}
$

\vskip 1cm
%\tikzcdset{column sep/normal=0.5cm}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0.5cm, row sep=0.7cm]
  & β\dlar \drar & & α\\
  b &  & a\arrow[ll]\urar\arrow[rr]&  & c \ular
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. I put the codes \begin{align}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0.5cm, row sep=0.7cm]
& \beta \dlar \drar & & \alpha \\
b &  & a \arrow[ll] \urar \arrow[rr] &  & c \ular
\end{tikzcd}
\end{align}

But there is an error: missing $ inserted. I don't know why. I already use begin{align}

Comment: The reason is TikZ-pdf uses the ampersand sign in a non-standard way, and `align` also uses ampersands. A workaround consists in adding to the options of tikz-cd `ampersand replacement=\&`, and replace `&` with `\&` in the diagram.

Comment: thank you very much. I wrote \usepackage[ampersand replacement=\&]{tikz-cd}. But there is an error: unknown option ampersand replacement=\&

Comment: Which version of `tikz-cd` and of `pgf` do you have? Present versions are  `0.9e` and `3.0.1` respectively.

Comment: thank you very much. How to check the version of tikz-cd and pgf?

Comment: It's written in the .log file, but the simplest if to add `\listfiles` *before* `\documentclass`. You'll have the list of all loaded files, with their versions, at the end of the .log file. If you have MiKTeX, MiKTeX Package Manager gives the list of files and version number for each package (right-click on  ‘Properties’).

Comment: thank you very much. My tikz-cd version is: Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76) and pgf version is: Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12). I tried to update the packages but there is some problem. I will try to use other methods to draw the quiver.

Comment: You really should update. Pgf had a major update when it came to version 3. What is your distribution? Also, do you really to have the quiver in an `amsmath` environment? Isn't `equation` or `\[ … \]` enough?

Comment: thank you very much. I will try to update. The distribution of Latex is 2.9.2.164.full. When I use \begin{equation}: \begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0.5cm, row sep=0.7cm]
& \beta \dlar \drar & & \alpha & \\ b & & a \arrow[ll] \urar \arrow[rr] & & c \ular
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation} There is an error: Arrow direction argument must contain only the characters l, r, u or d.

Comment: ??? I don't understand. All arrow direction arguments only contain the mentioned arguments. `\dlar`, `\drar`, `\ular`,`\urar` are shortcuts for `\arrow[dl]`, &c. Could post a link to a full code that produces this error message?

Comment: thank you very much. The following codes work: \begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0.5cm, row sep=0.7cm]
& \beta \arrow{dl} \arrow{dr} & & \alpha & \\ b & & a \arrow{ll} \arrow{ur} \arrow{rr} & & c \arrow{ul}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

Comment: Probably you should update tikz-cd to have access to the shortcuts and bug-fixes. Present version is `0.9e` (oct. 2014).

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions. I will update tikz-cd.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
& \beta \arrow[dl] \arrow[dr] && \alpha \\
b && a \arrow[ll] \arrow[ur] \arrow[rr] && c \arrow[ul]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it is elementary with Tikz, I think you need to try before asking a question.
Here is a response

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}              
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (a) at (0,0){a};

    \node[left=2cm of a] (b){b};

    \node[right=2cm of a] (c){c};

    \node[above right=1cm of a] (alpha){$\alpha$};

    \node[above left=1cm of a] (beta){$\beta$};

    \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
    \draw[->] (a) -- (c);
    \draw[->] (beta) -- (a);
    \draw[->] (beta) -- (b);

    \draw (a) -- (alpha);
    \draw (c) -- (alpha);

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without using any package:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c}
 &  & \beta &  &  &  & \alpha\\[-2pt]
 & \swarrow &  & \searrow &  & \nearrow &  & \nwarrow\\[-2pt]
b &  &  \makebox[0pt]{\overleftarrow{~~~~~~~}} &  & a &  & \makebox[0pt]{\overrightarrow{~~~~~~~}} &  & c
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

And, well, still exists the old picture environment:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{.5mm}
\begin{picture}(100,25)(2,0)
\put(10,0){$b$}
\put(50,0){$a$}
\put(90,0){$c$}
\put(30,20){$\alpha$}
\put(70,20){$\beta$}
\put(48,1){\vector(-1,0){32}}
\put(57,1){\vector(1,0){32}}
\put(30,18){\vector(-1,-1){14}}
\put(35,18){\vector(1,-1){14}}
\put(70,17){\vector(-1,-1){14}}
\put(75,17){\vector(1,-1){14}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```