# How to draw a quiver in latex like this?

Tags: graphs

How can I draw a quiver in latex? Even if a simple one like this:
[image: quiver]

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237778/4427

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such a simple quiver, you only need  elementary tools:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, old-arrows}

\begin{document}

$\overset{1}{\scriptstyle\circ} \xleftarrow{\;\alpha\;}\overset{2}{\scriptstyle\circ} \xrightarrow{\;\beta\;}\overset{3}{\scriptstyle\circ}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**1st mode)** Using the [`xymatrix`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xymatrix) package, you will have the same tips of your image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
\overset{1}{\circ} &
\ar[l]_{\alpha}\overset{2}{\circ}\ar[r]^{\beta}  &
\overset{3}{\circ} 
}
\end{document}
```

With the syntax `\xymatrix@C-=0.4cm` you can decrease the lenght of the arrows. With the syntax `\xymatrix@C+=0.4cm` you can increase the lenght of the arrows.
Here there is another example how to decrease the lenght of two arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C-=0.4cm{
\overset{1}{\circ} &
\ar[l]_{\alpha}\overset{2}{\circ}\ar[r]^{\beta}  &
\overset{3}{\circ} 
}
\end{document}
```

**2nd mode)** Using the [`tikz-cd`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package. With the option `[column sep=.7cm]` you can increase or decrease, indirectly, as if it were a matrix, the lenghts of the arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=.7cm]
\overset{1}{\circ} & \overset{2}{\circ} \arrow[l, "\alpha"'] \arrow[r, "\beta"] & \overset{3}{\circ}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```