# Quivers and Latex

Tags: diagrams

Can someone show me how to draw this quiver?
Thank you very much[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237778/tikz-for-gabriel-and-auslander-reiten-quivers and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232968/how-to-draw-quivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are examples in [Tikz for Gabriel and Auslander-Reiten quivers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237778/tikz-for-gabriel-and-auslander-reiten-quivers) and [How to draw quivers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232968/how-to-draw-quivers)

For your particular quiver, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1ex]
&&& 4 \\
1 \arrow[r] & 2 & 3 \arrow[l] \arrow[ur] \arrow[dr] \\
&&& 5
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]